# Connecting 2 Displays with a MacBook in serie does not work

Tags: macos, mac, display, macbook, display-settings

I'm trying to connect the MacBook A1286 / A1278 (got 2) in this following configuration:

[image: Connection Setup]

I can do that with Windows and the monitors just fine. And it works perfectly, but when I try it with MacBook there's just only ever 2 Display, the MacBook display, and the 2 monitors are cloned. There's no way to have them as seperate displays. No option for that, or I'm not seeing it.

That said, I'm not too familiar myself with Mac OSX, so there's that.

The Monitors in questions are DELL Ultrasharp U2415b.

How can I make it so they are 2 seperate displays, not cloned ones?

Comment: According to Everymac, neither of those machines are capable of supporting two external displays.

Comment: So...I need a docking port of sorts?! If so, any suggestions please? I'm out of my depth with macs.

Comment: No, one external display is your maximum.